# How can I display text only on the collapsed navbar in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'd like to display a telephone number that appears on the navbar next to the navbar toggle button. The toggle button only appears once the navbar is in the collapsed state. I'd like the text to appear next to it.

Here's what I have now:

[image: collapsed navbar]

And here's what I am trying to achieve:

[image: collapsed navbar with text]

HTML from the relevant divs:

```
<div class="header-centered"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't want the text to appear unless the navbar is collapsed. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control the visibility of your text by CSS, something like this:

```
.abcde .text {
  display: none;
}
.abcde.collapse .text {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: What is .abcde here? Cause I don't see any .collapse added dynamically

Comment: This answer misses entirely the bootstrap context.

Answer (score 3):

Easy - just add the following HTML right before the 'hamburger button'

```
<p class="navbar-text visible-xs-inline-block">Menu</p>
```

Then style it to suit.

```
p.navbar-text {  
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  text-align: right;
  width: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are too many ways to handle this situation.

1. `Display: none;` It's a browser friendly, they no more assume any element because its in permanently hidden state.
2. `Visibility: hidden;` it can hide any element on your document but still it has a limitation, browsers'll have to find that element on the page and then they hide that element. So for a few of few milliseconds but they have to work a bit to hide this.
3. By keeping `font-size: 0;` and after collapsing state use `font-size: 1em;`.
4. Keep `opacity: 0` and later on `opacity: 1`.
5. `postion: absolute;` `left:-99999em;` and and later `left:0;`
6. You can use z-index if you have positioned element. Stacking the element in order also works.

So, finally there are a whole bunch of methods to hide and show elements on your document. It all depends on you whatever you choose.
But according to me `Display: none;` is the best one for your project.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for the answer and this is what I did - replace Menu with your desired text

```
<div class="navbar-inner">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="btn btn-navbar btn-block" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
      <span class="icon icon-white icon-align-justify"></span>
    MENU</a>
    <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-inverse-collapse">
      <ul class="nav">
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this answer for users that want to use bootstrap way of handling collapsing element using the grid-float-breakpoint , that is the point at which the navbar becomes uncollapsed.

So if you want elements that is visible only when the bar is collapsed add the *collapsed-addon* class and include this css.

**The default gird-float-breakpoint value is setted to screen-sm-min that is 768px**

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .collapsed-addon {
    display: none;
}
```

**If you are using some processors use the css variable grid-float-breakpoint**

```
@media (min-width: $grid-float-breakpoint){
  .collapsed-addon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```